# Pick up phone call with voice

Tags: calls, accessibility, voice-command

I am disabled (quadriplegic) and therefore cannot press the answer and hang up buttons on my smartphone to answer a phone call. On my Samsung S6 EDGE phone (Android 7), there is a function in the settings to pick up the phone by saying "answer". The problem is that since Android 8, this function no longer exists.

As I would like to change my telephone, I would not like to find myself unprepared. That's why I would like to know if it would be possible that I could make from an application or a script a system that allows me to press the pick up a button and hang up the phone when I say "pick up" or "hang up".

Comment: *"Alice"* - a friend recommended me this app few years ago - he used this for hands free text-to-speech listening incoming sms, make phone calls etc while driving car. the link is free pro-version of [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourapp24.android.tools.alice_lite) (not in store). note: I haven't tested this app but guess you need help for initial setup. sure there are similar/better apps in google play store out there

Comment: refer to FAQ click on [Why can't I buy/update the Pro-Version?](http://www.yourapp24.com/en/aivc_faq.html) -> [download the Pro-Version for free here](http://www.yourapp24.com/en/file/download?id=yourapp24.android.tools.aivc)

Comment: I just installed your version on my phone only I don't understand the system that allows you to pick up or hang up a phone call.

Comment: try other similar apps (or maybe let a friend call you and you will asked to pick up?)

Comment: I tried to find similar apps on the Play store but unfortunately I couldn't find any. Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134169/discussion-between-tatane-and-alecxs).

Answer (score 1):

The accessibility app [Voice Access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess) might help.

According to [Get started with Voice Access spoken commands](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151848), some of the prerequisites:

- Only available in English, Spanish, German, Italian, or French.
- Requires Android version 5.0 or later.
- Requires [Google app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox).

According to [Use Voice Access commands](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151854?hl=en#zippy=%2Cbasics-navigation), after Voice Access is enabled, it is at least possible to answer a call by saying "answer call".

> #### Answer calls
>
> If you receive a call, you can answer it by saying "Answer call."

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a WearOS watch that links to your phone and comes with voice assistant.
https://wearos.google.com/intl/en_ca/#works-on
The added bonus being that the phone can stay in your pocket or a belt clip/ holster !
You may even find one that is compatible with your current phone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).